# selecting groups with zero values by action column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr

I have next data

```
    mydat=structure(list(group = c(111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 
111L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 555L, 555L, 555L, 
555L, 555L, 555L, 555L), group2 = c(222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 
222L, 222L, 444L, 444L, 444L, 444L, 444L, 444L, 444L, 666L, 666L, 
666L, 666L, 666L, 666L, 666L), action = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L
), x1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 20L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("group", "group2", 
"action", "x1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L
))
```

Here two group variables(group and group2) .
there are three group

```
111 222
333 444
555 666
```

action column can take value only 0 and 1.

So i need find these groups where for 1 category of action they have only zero values by x1.
in our case it is

```
111 222
333 444
```

because for all 1 category  of action they have zeros by x1.
So i can work only with `555    666` group. 
because it has at least one non-zero value of  first category of action by x1 variable.

The desired output
`Mydat1` here groups with at least one non-zero value of  first category of action by x1 variable.

```
group   group2  action  x1
555      666    0   1
555      666    0   2
555      666    0   3
555      666    1   **10**
555      666    1   **20**
555      666    0   1
555      666    0   2
```

`mydat2` groups  which for all 1 category  of action they have zeros by x1

```
group   group2  action  x1
111      222    0   1
111      222    0   2
111      222    0   3
111      222    1   **0**
111      222    1   **0**
111      222    0   1
111      222    0   2
333      444    0   1
333      444    0   2
333      444    0   3
333      444    1   **0**
333      444    1   **0**
333      444    0   1
333      444    0   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i correctly you, then understand your question is:

> i need find these groups where for 1 category of action they have
>   only zero values by x1.

so here is the response:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydat  %>%
  group_by( action ) %>%
  filter( action==1 & x1==0 )
```

and the response is:

```
  group group2 action    x1
  <int>  <int>  <int> <int>
1   111    222      1     0
2   111    222      1     0
3   333    444      1     0
4   333    444      1     0
```

*What does this code do?*

it looks at `action` feature, and consider 2 main categories for all rows(0,and 1). Then it filters out the observations which pass `action==1 & x1==0`. So, it means, among those rows who have `action==1` the `x1==0` is true as well.

> can script return all values of 555+666 group?

**No**. it does not return these 2 groups. And it should not do that. Let's write a code which filters 555,and 666

```
library(tidyverse)
mydat  %>%
  group_by( action ) %>%
  filter( group==555 | group2==666 )
```

and the result is:

```
group group2 action    x1
  <int>  <int>  <int> <int>
1   555    666      0     1
2   555    666      0     2
3   555    666      0     3
4   555    666      1    10
5   555    666      1    20
6   555    666      0     1
7   555    666      0     2
```

so, as you can see, none of these observation fulfills the condition `action==1 & x1==0` . Therefore, they are not among the valid response.

Comment: Salman, all right, but  in addtion of your output, can script return all values of  555+666 group? So script must return your output (let's it called mydat2) and all rows for 555+666, group. because it has at least one non-zero value of first category of action by x1 variable. (The groups where at least one non-zero value of first category of action by x1 variable must be in output mydat1 ).

Comment: @D.Joe i don't agree with you. Let me first update my answer with extra explanation and then we can talk.